# Is it haram to use the human voice to imitate the sound of musical instruments?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, music

Music is generally haram (but with exceptions). However, I was introduced to the idea that one is allowed to use voice as an instrument, and thereby produce sound that almost *exactly* like a sound produce by an instrument. So far, I have heard people doing this only for sound or together with Islamic Nasheed.

However, is this way of “playing music without an instrument” halal or haram? (On the pre-condition, of course, that the music is either pure sound or contains no lyrics which go against Islamic principles.)

These questions are related, but do not answer this question:

- [What is the Islamic definition of music?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/what-is-the-islamic-definition-of-music)
- [Is Auto-tunes Haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/is-auto-tunes-haram)
- [Is listening to Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited) in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/music-in-islam/248#248)

Please answer with references to the Quran and Hadith where possible.

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9710/arent-nasheeds-a-serious-waste-of-time

Answer (score 1):

**Yeah! it is Haraam as it is giving same result and producing instrumental sound.**

Check fatwa of Sheikh Muhammed Salih Al-Munajjid for more details:  https://islamqa.info/en/193426

Answer (score -2):

There is controversial discussion in Muslim communities. I concluded that music is haram, as soon as it brings you into a silly mood that distracts you from your sense of responsibility for this life on earth. 
You may [check that reference](https://islamqa.info/en/5000) for further details. But keep in mind, that all statements should be rooted on Quran & [Sunnah](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/55).

Answer (score -3):

Haram Music is the one which make us far from God. But we have some other musics that make us thinking about Allah, our jobs and other things. Totally, Listening to Haram music is Haram, but listening to unharam music is voluntary.

Specifically answer to your question is: If playing music with human voice is for composing Haram music, so it is Haram. But if that written music is not Haram so playing with voice is not Haram.

Ulamas have different Fatwas on Haram and Halal music. So it is better you revert to the person you follow.

Comment: This is the first time that I have come across this classification of music as both haraam and halaal... I thought music was totally and unconditionally haraam. Can you please cite your sources?

Comment: @Fatermeh Its dangerous to give opinion without reference. plz provide your authentic reference. jazaklahir!

Answer (score -3):

Music is not haram. Qur'an specifically names other books which are guidance, one of which is Zabur, or book of Psalms. Most of the Psalms were written specifically to be accompanied by music, often stating which musical instrument the psalm was intended to be accompanied with.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE. This seems like a better answer to 
[Is listening to Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited) in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/237/17163) than this question.  I'd also encourage you to build on this answer by (a) showing where in the Qur'an the book of Psalms is mentioned and (b) by providing evidence for "Most of the Psalms were written specifically to be accompanied by music".

Comment: I cannot find any evidence for your claim "to be accompanied by music"